# Access generated primary key on ImageField upload_to call

Tags: python, django

I have a model where my goal is to generate the primary key (a character string) and then rename the uploaded file to match that string. This is my shortened model and the `upload_to` function I use.

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=16)
    photo = ImageField('Photo', upload_to=upload_path, null=False, blank=False)
    ...



def upload_path(instance, filename):
    if not instance.id:
        randid = random_id(16)    # This returns a 16 character string of ASCII characters
        while Thing.objects.filter(id=randid).exists():
            logger.error("[Thing] ThingID of %s already exists" % randid)
            randid = random_id(16)
        instance.id = randid
    return "%s%s" % ("fullpath/",randid)
```

This results in the image being properly renamed to a random string in the appropriate path. The primary key, however, is set to an empty string.

How can I use a generated primary key to rename an ImageField file *and* properly save the primary key that is generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the `upload_to` call back and doing this all in `Thing`'s `save()` method.

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=16)
    photo = ImageField('Photo', upload_to=upload_path, null=False, blank=False)
    ...


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        randid = random_id(16)
        while Thing.objects.filter(id=randid).exists():
            logger.error("[Thing] ThingID of %s already exists" % randid)
            randid = random_id(16)
        self.id = randid
        self.photo.name = ".".join([randid, self.photo.name.split(".")[-1]])   # This adds the file extension to the random id generated
        super(Thing,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this trough defining save method on Model. Set True **null** and **blank** ImageField, if you have to control empty fields, you can control them on model form. So you can easily generate unique id on DB for model. Then you can save your image with unique id or your custom generated id. Better use default unique integer id for primary key I suggest.

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    fake_id = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    photo = ImageField('Photo', upload_to=upload_path, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        imagefile = self.photo

        self.photo = ''
        super(Thing, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    """ after superclass save, you can use self.id also its unique integer """

        randid = random_id(16)    # This returns a 16 character string of ASCII characters
        while Thing.objects.filter(id=randid).exists():
            logger.error("[Thing] ThingID of %s already exists" % randid)
            randid = random_id(16)

       self.fake_id = randid

   """manipulate rename and upload your file here you object is 'imagefile' """

       save_dir = "fullpath/" + new_file_name_with_randid

       self.photo = save_dir

       super(Thing, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This solution does not work. It does two things incorrectly: 1.) It inserts two separate entries into the database. The first entry is an empty entry with no file associated correctly. The second entry has a file name and id associated correctly, but no file is actually uploaded with the correct name.

Comment: I left upload job to you. Actually this code works great, of course it's not complete code, so I'm not doing your homework, trying to help you.